# manipulate 'temporary dom' at background

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is bit tough question.  I"m using third party library that will insert result into DOM.

Example:

```
$('#puthere').thirdpartyplugin();
```

this will call `thirdpartyplugin` and manipulate result of HTML element `#puthere`.

My question is, how to output result to JavaScript variable rather than DOM element?

```
var plainOutput =  $.thirdpartyplugin();  alert(plainOutput);
```

I do not want to manipulate HTML element that is visible to users. I just want to call `alert(plainOutput)` the result.

Comment: Without knowing what this "thirdpartyplugin" is or what it does, how can anybody possibly tell you? *edit* well I suppose they can take a guess :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a temporary element:

```
var $out = $('<div />');
$out.thirdpartyplugin();
alert($out.html()): // or .text();
```

This might or might not work, depending on what the plugin is doing.

If the plugin plays by the rules and supports method chaining, you can also do:

```
var $out = $('<div />').thirdpartyplugin().html();
```